# Composition by exponentiation of measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

A measurable function is defined the following way:

> $f:X \rightarrow [-\infty, +\infty]$ such that $f^{-1}((-\infty, a))\in \mathcal{M} \ \  \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$

Then, there is this following problem:

> Given $E$ a measurable set, $f,g:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x), g(x) \geq 1 \ \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ measurable funcitions then $h:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined $h(x):=f(x)^{g(x)}$ is measurable.

I've tried applying the definition directly but i fail to see how to solve the problem. I would appreciate some help or hints on the proof.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The composition of continuous mapping with a measurable mapping is measurable. Try use this. And also product of two measurable is measurable.

Comment: Sorry but what exactly do you mean by mapping? I study maths in spanish so im not familiar with some english therms

Comment: mapping = function

Comment: just note that $h(x)=\exp\left(g(x)\cdot \ln f(x)\right)$, that is, $h$ is composition of measurable functions